# xcode causing a UIImageView to stop in the place of intersection with another UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I can't seem to figure this one out??
It should be simple.

There should be a method in existence already to perform this. I'm building a game where a character fires an object (`UIImageView`) and all I need is to make that object stay put in exactly the same location it intersects the other `UIImageView`. For instance, if it were target practice, an object fired stops in the place it hits the target. The `UIImageView` that is being targeted is scrolling across the screen as well so when implemented properly, I should see the 1st image land and stop in the location it intersects the 2nd image and then proceed to scroll off the screen in the place it landed.
How do I accomplish this???  Please help!

I've been scouring everywhere online including here and apple developer library. I was trying to use `CGRectIntersectsRect` but it seems to only deal with the whole frame of the image, not the specific point of intersection.  So I tried `CGRectIntersection` but it seems I may not quite understand how to implement it. The developer library hasn't seemed to clarify this very well. I've also attempted to copy the image and place it...  Do I need to check for the coordinates of the intersection point?  If so, how?  Here's the last thing I've tried:

**NOTE**:
`img1` gets properly placed and moves across the screen as expected. `img2` also moves as expected.

```
-(void)img1Moving
{

    img1.center = CGPointMake(img1.center.x + 5, img1.center.y + 20);

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(img1.frame, img2.frame)) {

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

        imgView.bounds**or frame** = CGRectIntersection(img1.frame, img2.frame);
        [self.view addSubview:imgView];

        //OR

        imgView.frame = 
    }
}
```

The last line puts the game into a flickering loop...

So, I messed around with:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(img1.frame, img2.frame)) {

    img1.frame = CGRectIntersection(img1.frame, img2.frame);        
}
```

** I've tried using a number of different calls here with `CGPointMake` and a few other things.  I can't recall all the different ways I've tried this...**

The best I've been able to accomplish is using a transparent `UIImage` to intersect with `img1` and CGPointMake to leave `img1` in the general vicinity of `img2`. But of course this isn't the effect I'm looking for.

PLEASE HELP ME UNDERSTAND WHAT I'M MISSING

Answer (score 0):

Wow! my apologies...  That was incredibly simple...  Can't believe I got stuck on it...

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(img1.frame, img2.frame)) {

    img1.center = CGPointMake(img1.center.x +/- #, img2.center.y);
}
```

of course this is for an object moving horizontally.  To track it vertically just reverse the factors for x and y

```
    img1.center = CGPointMake(img2.center.x, img1.center.y +/- #);
```